# C# connect with com-object

Tags: c#, com

Is there in C# connect to COM-object and use contents of com-object such as in the Builder c++:

```
CreateOleObject("some.someClass");
```

(OLE C # seems to be not supported, except OLEDb, but it is not the current case in my opinion)
I know I can add a link -> COM -> Seeking a registered com-object.

But it does not fit.

Comment: search term is [COM interop](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+com+interop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, if you need to use a COM object in C#, you would add it as a Reference, and select the registered type library. That will generate an Interop Assembly, after which you can use the COM object just like any other C# class.

Alternatively, you can run the .NET utility [`tlbimp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(v=vs.110).aspx) by hand, which has roughly the same effect but gives you slightly more control.

If you really need to create the object dynamically, without knowing anything about the type ahead of time, you can use the `dynamic` keyword and the `Activator` class to create a dynamic instance of a type. The code would look like:

```
var comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("some.someClass");
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
```

This will defer all type checking on `obj` until run-time, behaving much like VBA would.